# Flutter Dart how to trim if special characters are present?

Tags: flutter, dart, special-characters, utf-16

I would like to trim text in flutter, but text might have emojis and other special characters, and the normal trim method would result in crashing the app (text widget cannot interpret resulut)

Example

```
Text(
                            trim("testsomethin la ba kalom ", 28),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: Dimen.mediumText,
                            ),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
```

I hardcoded the string, but in real world it is a user generated text (let say chat system), and we recieved a lot of crashes due to this.

Just run the above, and you will experience a crash.

In other languages like `php` for example, can do multibyte string trimming, by workarounds like

```
$userText = "testsomethin la ba kalom ";
$trimed = mb_substr(
                $userText,
                0,
                min(28, strlen($userText))
            );
```

This is my trim implementation now

```
class FormatMixin {
  trim(String s, int trimLength) {
    return '${s.substring(0, s.length <= trimLength ? s.length : trimLength)}${s.length <= trimLength ? '' : '...'}';
  }
}
```

How can I trim text that contain special chars emojis, utf-16 text basically in dart/flutter ?

I will give **test cases below of expected result**, for our custom `mbTrim` function:

```
text = "testmesocoolabc"

1. mbTrim(text, 6) = "testme"
2. mbTrim(text, 7) = "testme"
3. mbTrim(text, 8) = "testmes"
```

So logic is that if special char is found, it need to be fully included or excluded. (exaclty what i could do server side with php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Characters package](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) for handling strings without breaking emojis.

Your `mbtrim` example could be implemented as:

```dart
String mbtrim(String text, int length) =>
   text.characters.take(length).toString();
```

For many simple tasks like the above, [`Characters`](https://pub.dev/documentation/characters/latest/characters/Characters-class.html) (via `.characters`) is sufficient.

For more involved editing you might need to use the [`CharacterRange`](https://pub.dev/documentation/characters/latest/characters/CharacterRange-class.html) class. If you are doing something complicated in a loop, it is often more convenient and efficient to do it by updating a `CharacterRange` rather than using indexes, so try to see of you can work with the `CharacterRange` and convert back to a String only when you are done.

Comment: Tested this and work correctly with given test cases in question, working as expected same as mb_string in php. Accepted as solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegExp`

```
  void main() {
      String text = "testsomethin la ba kalom ";
      final RegExp regExp = RegExp(
          r'(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])');
    
      if (text.contains(regExp)) {
        text = text.replaceAll(regExp, '');
      }
    
      print(text); /// output: testsomethin la ba kalom

    }
```

**Note:** For this kind of business logic, lots of test cases should be there.

Comment: thanks for hint, but will this be handling all possible utf-16 special chars, all possible emojis and so on ? I don't want to hardcode something to handle only  and a set of possible emojis. Idea is this, if we specify to trim at most 24 characters, and character 22-25 are   this emoji, then this should be ignored and triming can stop at 22, or include this emoji also but not split in middle some special char and then textfield crash

Comment: Also your regex is not trimming anything right ? Is just removing special chars if i understood correctly. The emojis should stay there, but just trimming should not split in middle one special char as in the above comment

Comment: I will try to make it easier to udnerstand with one testcase.

Comment: `text = "testmeafteremoji" trim(text, 6) should result in testme, trim(text, 7) should result in testme, trim(text,8) should result in testmea`  So here trim looks like need to be some custom implementation, a function like `mbTrim` And instead of  can be any available emoji or special char should be handled utf-16, generic implementation

Comment: yes this should remove emoji and special chars, and trim function you have to create or use another lib for it

Comment: I would recommend you to right test cases for your all possible combinations

Comment: I added in bottom of question the testcases. @jitesh What do you mean by combinations, I added 3 test cases to show all combinations, then instead of emoji can be any special chars those combinations all of them should be handled

Comment: okay @KristiJorgji if you are confident then nothing like it. :)

Comment: I am confident because that is the result I am getting in php (doing same logic but server side trimming user chat messages to X characters, before sending notifications). Now need to make similar logic in flutter client in the chat mesages list, to show only X characters in the contants page. So that is the requirement I mean, how to implement in flutter i do no know that is why I ask here, but I know that is possible in php and shared also code in php how i do it. The given test cases in php solution would be met

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235278/discussion-between-jitesh-mohite-and-kristi-jorgji).